# Is the C# library MPXJ able to read in a file from a MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, memorystream, mpxj

I am using [the library MPXJ](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/) which works great but I now want the ability for users to upload their own file (asp.net-mvc site) and it comes on the server side form post as a HttpPostedFileBase and I then I convert to a memory stream using:

```
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    httpPostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
```

Given that, I am trying to figure out how i can read it in as a MemoryStream (versus a file location on disk)

Right now I have something like this:

```
    public ProjectFile Import(string filePathandName)
    {
        MPPReader reader = new MPPReader();
        ProjectFile project = reader.read(filePathandName);
```

and i wanted to have something like this:

```
    public ProjectFile Import(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        MPPReader reader = new MPPReader();
        ProjectFile project = reader.read(stream);
```

Is this possible "natively" or do i need to save the file on my server and then read in from there (trying to avoid that option)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MPPReader.Read()` method only accepts 4 types of parameters, none of which are a `MemoryStream` and all but one seem to be types that are defined within the library itself:

- **java.io.File**
- **java.io.InputStream**
- **org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem**
- **string**

You are currently using the `string` parameter as it expects a path, however it seems the closest that you might get would be to try to copy your existing `MemoryStream` object to the `InputStream` type found within the library and using that (if that type of support exists).

Answer (score 1):

MPXJ ships with a pair of classes called `DotNetInputStream` and `DotNetOutputStream` which act as wrappers around .Net streams so that they can be used where MPXJ is expecting Java `InputStream` or `OutputStream`.

Here is the relevant comment from `DotNetInputStream`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Implements a wrapper around a .Net stream allowing it to be used with MPXJ
/// where a Java InputStream is expected.
/// This code is based on DotNetInputStream.java from the Saxon project http://www.sf.net/projects/saxon
/// Note that I've provided this class as a convenience so there are a matching pair of
/// input/output stream wrapper shopped with MPXJ. IKVM also ships with an input stream wrapper:
/// ikvm.io.InputStreamWrapper, which you could use instead of this one.
/// </summary>
```

You should be able to use this class to achieve what you describe in your question.